# Making DataTables responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatables

Environment: Ruby 2.0.0, Rails 4.0.3, Windows 8.1 Update, jquery-datatables-rails 2.2.1, jquery-ui-rails 5.0.0, jquery-rails 3.1.1

I have DataTables up and running, but I need to make my tables responsive.  I'm confused by the instructions to do so.  I have written some JavaScript but not Coffee.  Either way, I'm not sure what to do.

The jquery-datatables-rails instructions say:

```
5 - Initialize your datatables using:

responsiveHelper = undefined
breakpointDefinition =
  tablet: 1024
  phone: 480

tableElement = $("#example")
tableElement.dataTable
  autoWidth: false
  preDrawCallback: ->

    # Initialize the responsive datatables helper once.
    responsiveHelper = new ResponsiveDatatablesHelper(tableElement, breakpointDefinition)  unless responsiveHelper
    return

  rowCallback: (nRow) ->
    responsiveHelper.createExpandIcon nRow
    return

  drawCallback: (oSettings) ->
    responsiveHelper.respond()
    return
```

I currently initialize my tables doing this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Enable any datatables
    $('#datatable').dataTable({
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        bJQueryUI: true
    });
    $('#carstable').dataTable({
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        bJQueryUI: true,
        bProcessing: true,
        bServerSide: true,
        sAjaxSource: $('#carstable').data('source')
    });
```

I used compileonline.com to generate the JavaScript:

```
(function() {
  var breakpointDefinition, responsiveHelper, tableElement;

  responsiveHelper = void 0;

  breakpointDefinition = {
    tablet: 1024,
    phone: 480
  };

  tableElement = $("#example");

  tableElement.dataTable({
    autoWidth: false,
    preDrawCallback: function() {
      if (!responsiveHelper) {
        responsiveHelper = new ResponsiveDatatablesHelper(tableElement, breakpointDefinition);
      }
    },
    rowCallback: function(nRow) {
      responsiveHelper.createExpandIcon(nRow);
    },
    drawCallback: function(oSettings) {
      responsiveHelper.respond();
    }
  });

}).call(this);
```

But I cannot see what I need to do to integrate that into my current JavaScript initializer.

Comment: Have you tried looking here? https://github.com/Comanche/datatables-responsive

Comment: The data and its columns.  According to the documents, it should be able to resize and I should be able to drop selected columns as it does so.

Comment: @ZeeTee  Yes, I did look there.  I'm trying to use the Rails port.  And, it seems to raise the same question with similar code.  Thanks.

Comment: You might wanna try posting this on datatables.net  Allan or someone should be able to help there. If not, I believe Allan offers extended support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Staring at the code long enough sometimes resolves the problem...  I have it basically working, though I'll need to customize it.  The replacement code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var breakpointDefinition, responsiveHelper, tableElement;
    responsiveHelper = void 0;
    breakpointDefinition = {
        tablet: 1024,
        phone: 480
    };
    tableElement = $("#datatable");
    tableElement.dataTable({
        autoWidth: false,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        bJQueryUI: true,
        preDrawCallback: function() {
            if (!responsiveHelper) {
                responsiveHelper = new ResponsiveDatatablesHelper(tableElement, breakpointDefinition);
            }
        },
        rowCallback: function(nRow) {
            responsiveHelper.createExpandIcon(nRow);
        },
        drawCallback: function(oSettings) {
            responsiveHelper.respond();
        }
    });
    tableElement = $("#carstable");
    tableElement.dataTable({
        autoWidth: false,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        bJQueryUI: true,
        bProcessing: true,
        bServerSide: true,
        sAjaxSource: $('#carstable').data('source'),
        preDrawCallback: function() {
            if (!responsiveHelper) {
                responsiveHelper = new ResponsiveDatatablesHelper(tableElement, breakpointDefinition);
            }
        },
        rowCallback: function(nRow) {
            responsiveHelper.createExpandIcon(nRow);
        },
        drawCallback: function(oSettings) {
            responsiveHelper.respond();
        }
    });
```